# How to group rows by ID in format suitable for CSV export?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following table:

```
Row ID          AltID1      Latitude    Longitude   AltID2  
1   16055000700 292367877   47.724477   -116.826249 83815818845
2   16055000700 292367882   47.724906   -116.827074 83815819235 
3   16055000700 292409477   47.720201   -116.804307 83815834156 
...
396 16055000800 292413726   47.69276    -116.810874 83814559302
397 16055000800 292413725   47.692863   -116.811014 83814559312 
398 16055000800 292414050   47.693109   -116.811462 83814559728
```

e.g. a table with groups of multiple rows with same ID. Need to figure out how to group by ID and to get AltID1, Latitude, Longitude, AltID2 associated with ID. It should be exported to CSV and it needs to be designed for easy processing.

The end result should look like this:

```
line 1:
ID          Count   Data
16055000700 3       "[[292367877, 47.724477, -116.826249, 83815818845] ,[292367882, 47.724906, -116.827074, 83815819235], [292409477,47.720201,-116.804307,83815834156]]"
Line2:
...
```

The first column is the ID, second one - the number of rows associated with this ID in the original table, third one is array of arrays with 3 values each from AltID1, Latitude, Longitude, AltID2  columns from the original table.

Got some help with this code:

```
WITH
  data AS(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    UNNEST( ARRAY<STRUCT<id int64, altid1 int64, lat float64, lon float64, altid2 int64>> 
        [(16055000700,
        292367877,
        47.724477,
        -116.826249,
        83815818845), (16055000700,
        292367882,
        47.724906,
        -116.827074,
        83815819235), (16055000800,
        292414050,
        47.693109,
        -116.811462,
        83814559728)]
))
SELECT
  id,
  CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(to_json_STRING(ARRAY<float64>[altid1,
        lat,
        lon,
        altid2])), ']')
FROM
  data d
GROUP BY
  id
```

If I have a table MyTable
With schema:

```
FieldName   Type    Mode    
ID          INTEGER NULLABLE    
altid1      INTEGER NULLABLE    
lat         FLOAT   NULLABLE    
lon         FLOAT   NULLABLE    
altid2      INTEGER NULLABLE
```

How to generate this part with SELECT statement getting the data from MyTable?

```
           [(16055000700,
            292367877,
            47.724477,
            -116.826249,
            83815818845), (16055000700,
            292367882,
            47.724906,
            -116.827074,
            83815819235), (16055000800,
            292414050,
            47.693109,
            -116.811462,
            83814559728)]
```

Comment: Your question is not clear... Can you rephrase it?

Comment: the code above shows example with fixed values for Id, lat, log, etc. need a SELECT statement how to get them from a table

Comment: just did it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT ID, COUNT(1) rows_count, 
  CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(TO_JSON_STRING([AltID1, Latitude, Longitude, AltID2])), ']') data
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY ID
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 16055000700 ID, 292367877 AltID1, 47.724477 Latitude, -116.826249 Longitude, 83815818845 AltID2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 16055000700, 292367882, 47.724906, -116.827074, 83815819235 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 16055000700, 292409477, 47.720201, -116.804307, 83815834156 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 16055000800, 292413726, 47.69276, -116.810874, 83814559302 UNION ALL
  SELECT 16055000800, 292413725, 47.692863, -116.811014, 83814559312 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 16055000800, 292414050, 47.693109, -116.811462, 83814559728 
)
SELECT ID, COUNT(1) rows_count, 
  CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(TO_JSON_STRING([AltID1, Latitude, Longitude, AltID2])), ']') data
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY ID
```

with result

```sql
Row ID          rows_count  data     
1   16055000700 3           [[292367877,47.724477,-116.826249,83815818845],[292367882,47.724906,-116.827074,83815819235],[292409477,47.720201,-116.804307,83815834156]]  
2   16055000800 3           [[292413726,47.69276,-116.810874,83814559302],[292413725,47.692863,-116.811014,83814559312],[292414050,47.693109,-116.811462,83814559728]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TO_JSON_STRING()` to get results close to the desired results. Then aggregate those string into a larger one:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod2017`
  WHERE stn IN ('998258','995011','996080') AND mo="02" AND da<'03'
)

SELECT stn, FORMAT('[%s]', STRING_AGG(values)) values
FROM (
  SELECT stn, TO_JSON_STRING([min,max,temp]) values
  FROM `data`
)
GROUP BY 1
```

[image]